# Finding a measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a metric space with $\sigma$ algebra Borel $B(X)$ and let $\mu$ be a mesure on $X$. We define the support of $\mu$ to be the smallest set $F$ such that $F$ is closed and $\mu(F^C)=0$.

Let $F\subseteq [0,1]$ be a closed set. show there is a measure on $[0,1]$ such that her support is $F$

How to approach this question? What is the intuition beyond the support of a measure?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich edited, this is how the question was written

Comment: Why not define $\mu(A)=1$ if and only if $A\supseteq F$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur How do you propose to show countable additivity?

Comment: Okay, what if we revise it to $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A\supseteq F$ and $\mu(A)=0$ if $A\nsupseteq F$? He didn't add any other assumptions, so it seems to me that there maybe be trivial degenerate measures which satisfy this.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Do you actually know something that you think is a proof or are these just random guesses? In fact with either version the union of countably many null sets need not be a null set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A\cap F\ne \emptyset$ and $0$, otherwise.

Comment: 1. For any $A\in [0,1]$ we have $\mu(A)\geq 0$ 2. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ 3. how do we show sigma additivity?

Comment: @newhere $\sigma$-additivity is trivial here.

Comment: I can not see it :(

Comment: Suppose you have a disjoint collection of sets $\{A_i\}$. If $\mu(A_i)=0$ for all $i$, then $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i \cap F=\emptyset$ and $\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\right)=0$, otherwise $\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\right)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of the same idea as the other answer, but a *finite* measure:

As often, define a measure $\delta_p$ concentrated at $p$ by $$\delta_p(E)=\begin{cases}1,&(p\in E),
\\0,&(p\notin E).\end{cases}$$

Say $(p_j)_1^\infty$ is a countable dense subset of $F$ and let $$\mu=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}\delta_{p_j}.$$